# Labelling boxplot X axis with years

Tags: r, csv

My read in .csv file has the year names across the top first row, each column signifying a different year. While I can get the boxplot to generate properly, the X-axis labels are incorrect with every year having an X in from of it

Example: 2003    2004     2005
What I get:  X2003    X2004    X2005

Trying to manually add the names gives me the following message:

```
boxplot(a1, names="2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015", xlab="Year", ylab="Total length (cm)")
```

The error I get is: Error in axis(side = 1, at = 1:13, labels = "2003") : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 13 != 1

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can have a variable name that starts with a number... this could be the problem re: the X prefix.  Without seeing all of your reproducible code I can't try the following myself, but does the names parameter expect a vector?  Try names=c("2003",... ) instead to see if that gets you further.

Comment: That's what I just did. I just changed the names in the dataframe using the colnames function.